# other desktop environments is not working

Tags: desktop-environment, gdm3, pop-os

I installed xfce4 desktop environment.

But when I select it, it does not enter and only shows a black screen.

I installed other distributions but again encountered the same problem.

The screen turns black and shows nothing, and after a while the CPU crashes.

What is the reason?

I use pop_os.

please help,

thank you very much.

```
system = LENOVO Lenovo ideapad 320-15IKB 80XL

graphic : NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 920MX] / GeForce 920MX/PCIe/SSE2

processor: Intel® Core™ i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz × 4
```

[image: graphic card and drivers]

Comment: Have you had any graphical environment working? Which ones? What computer are you using (make+model)? What graphics card?

Comment: I edited my questions based on the questions you asked

Comment: Have you had any graphical environment running? If so, which one?

Comment: I did not understand exactly what you mean, but I think your answer is:
I use gnome

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop the display manager (`sudo systemctl isolate multi-user.target # or runlevel3.target`)
2. Switch to text console (Ctrl + Alt + F2-F6)
3. Run `X &` (your screen will turn black - that's intended)
4. Return to the same text console
5. Run `disown`
6. Run `export DISPLAY=:0`
7. Run `startxfce4`
8. Return to the same text console and check for any error messages on the screen.